# Discontinous colors while drawing networkx graphs with plotly

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, networkx, plotly-python

I am following this example showing how to draw networkx graphs with plotly: https://plotly.com/python/network-graphs

All I want is to find a way to use discontinuous color bar and the result should be something like ‘1’ is red, ‘2’ is blue etc. with no interpolation between integers. The numbers are already integers here, but as it is noted in the documentation (https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/), if the input is an array of numbers, it will be treated as a continues color scale.

I tried adding a str() around each appended number as

```
node_adjacencies.append(str(len(adjacencies[1])))
```

but it returns this error

> raise ValueError( ValueError:
> Invalid element(s) received for the 'color' property of scatter.marker
> Invalid elements include: ['12', '12', '15', '12', '9', '8', '4', '6', '8', '10']
>
> The 'color' property is a color and may be specified as:
> - A hex string (e.g. '#ff0000')
> - An rgb/rgba string (e.g. 'rgb(255,0,0)')
> - An hsl/hsla string (e.g. 'hsl(0,100%,50%)')
> - An hsv/hsva string (e.g. 'hsv(0,100%,100%)')
> - A named CSS color:
> aliceblue, antiquewhite, aqua, aquamarine, azure,
> beige, bisque, black, blanchedalmond, blue,
> blueviolet, ..., thistle, tomato,
> turquoise, violet, wheat, white, whitesmoke,
> yellow, yellowgreen
> - A number that will be interpreted as a color
> according to scatter.marker.colorscale
> - A list or array of any of the above

Any ideas how to fix this? Any alternative method to assign colors?

Thanks.

Comment: I found directions on the Plotly website. [Check it out](https://community.plotly.com/t/discontinous-colors-while-drawing-networkx-graphs/71584)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is posted in plotly web site and it's working:
https://community.plotly.com/t/discontinous-colors-while-drawing-networkx-graphs/71584